Spectral theory of compact operator for quasi-Banach spaces
Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $Y\subset X$ be a quasi-Banach space (with compact inclusion). Suppose $T:X\to X$ is a compact operator such that $1$ is not its eigenvalue and $T|_{Y}:Y\to Y$ is bounded operator. Clearly $X=\operatorname{im} (I_X-T)$.
My question is, do we must have $Y=\operatorname{im}(I_Y-T|_Y)$? Note that for every $y\in Y$ we know there is a unique $x\in X$ such that $x-Tx=y$, I just don't know whether $x\in Y$.
In practice I am considering Banach spaces $X_0\subset X_1$ and quasi-Banach space $X_0\subset Y\subset X_1$, $T:X_1\to X_1$ is a compact operator such that $T:X_0\to X_0$ is compact and $T:Y\to Y$ is bounded. The Riesz theory provides a decomposition $X_1=N\oplus R$ where $N=\operatorname{ker}((I-T)^m)$ and $R=\operatorname{im}((I-T)^m)$. Let $P_N:X_1\twoheadrightarrow N$ and $P_R:X_1\twoheadrightarrow X_1$ Since $T|_{X_0}:X_0\to X_0$ is compact we have $N\subset X_0$ hence $N\subset Y$ and $P_R|_Y:Y\to Y$ as well. My true question is, how to show $(I-P_R\circ T|_Y)^{-1}:Y\to Y$?
